how to extrude irregular shape
How do you extrude irregular indentation like this inwardly on the pictures?





I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "extrude inwards". You already seem to have the geo "extruded inwards" in the pic I'm seeing. It just looks like it needs to be cleaned up. Can you post examples of what you're aiming for and where you think you've gone wrong/are having problems?

First fill in the missing faces by selecting the edge ring around the missing faces, then delete the edge at either end of the selection so that you can use the Bridge Edge Loop tool from the edge menu. With the newly created faces still selected Alt + E to open the extrude menu and choose the Extrude Faces Along Normals option dragging the mouse downwards to move the extruded faces inwards.
